# Why wont my object cast as a UserControl wont display in asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, interface, casting, user-controls

My code grabs the search types from an XML document, grabs the first one, creates an instance of the user control for that search type and then populates it. I have casted the instance of it as a UserControl to try to get it to display but it wont. How do I make the populated instance of the user control display in the asp.net page?

```
void Display(List<DataResult> entityList)
    {
        List<SearchObjectType> searchTypes = SearchXMLParser.GetSearchTypes();
        SearchObjectType sot = searchTypes[0];
        ICard soType = sot.InstantiateSearchObject();

        foreach (DataResult entityObject in entityList)
        {
            soType.Populate(entityObject);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(((UserControl)soType)); /* this is the problem*/
```

Comment: Are you sure that `soType` is a `UserControl`? It's kinda 'scary' loading a UserControl from a XML Document. Instead I would guess you need a UserControl to handle the XML Node.

Comment: InstantiateSearchObject creates an instance of the user control (type is determined from the xml) and returns the object cast as a ICard